# Jquery Mobile & Cordova Event Pageinit Binding Wont Work

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

im Going mad after this... i followed a lot of pages even here in stack overflow but i cant make it to work

Bootstrap.js

```
var jqmReady = $.Deferred(),
pgReady = $.Deferred();

// jqm page is ready
$(document).bind("pageinit", jqmReady.resolve);

// phonegap ready
document.addEventListener("deviceready", pgReady.resolve, false);

// all ready, throw a custom 'PG_pageinit' event
$.when(jqmReady, pgReady).then(function () {
  $(document).trigger("xpageinit"); 
});
```

Index.html

```
$(document).bind("xpageinit", function(){


//Login Page
$('#login').live( 'pagebeforeload',function(event){


    $('a').buttonMarkup({ inline: true });
    $("#logo").fadeIn('slow', function(){
        $(this).animate({'top': '-=80px'},'slow', function(){
        $(".formLogin").fadeIn('slow');
        });    
    });  

    });

    });
```

but this wont work in any way, any suggestion?
thanks

Comment: This is tested and work without the xpageinit, so theres no problems in the Markup or anything like that... i also tested the xpageinit and it works too =/

Comment: You might try taking the jquery promises out of the equation, and see if the event bindings are working, just as a starting point.

Comment: i Dont understand why it doesnt work... we are binding when both are ready to bind the other event... if i put an alert() after "$(document).bind("xpageinit", function(){" it works, but the "$('#login').live( 'pagebeforeload',function(event){" doesnt get called at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you may be binding to the wrong method.  Instead of binding to the pagebeforeload, try binding to the pagebeforeshow event.  pagebeforeload is fired when the framework is going to load an external page.  I'm just guessing here, since you haven't given more details on what #login is (I'm assuming it's a div with a data-role="page" attribute.

Comment: i already figured it out, thanks, it was the wrong method in the wrong order ;)